# How to design a layout in Foundation with 7% empty space in left and right side?

Tags: zurb-foundation

While Designing website layout using foundation css,if i use grid system as bellow within the div with class row.its giving more space at left and right as in the Image.

[image]

```
The Code I am using is as bellow within the div with class="row"


<div class="row">
        <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">small-2 large-4 columns</div>
        <div class="small-4 large-4 columns">small-4 large-4 columns</div>
        <div class="small-6 large-4 columns">small-6 large-4 columns</div>
</div>
```

Here I need just 5-7% space both at left and right side.How to achieve this by using foundation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to change the width of class "row" of a foundation as much as we need.thats it we will get space at both left and right side.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Centered Columns in Foundation to do this.
  Small-1 row takes up 8.3333% so by the below html you can have space of 4.166% on the right and on the left.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-11 small-centered columns">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">small-2 large-4 columns</div>
        <div class="small-4 large-4 columns">small-4 large-4 columns</div>
        <div class="small-6 large-4 columns">small-6 large-4 columns</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Here is a fiddle-[link](http://jsfiddle.net/LVbZ2/16/)

Comment: @ParameshReddy same problem??wat problem?

Comment: As mentioned in Question by using your code I am not getting less width at both left and right side using foundation.I Found the solution that we need to change the width of class row as how much we want thats it.

Comment: Oops i missed a row div.And You can do it in a lot of ways but changing row css in foundation isin't one of them. for One it changes your page structure(unless you intentionally want to change it for the whole page dont go for it.).Second when you update to later versions of css you have to again add or change all the css you are changing now.

Comment: Not working if I load foundation.css.without foundation 100% working fine.As you suggested I am designing only layout so inline css I had added to change width of row so will not affect other screens right?

Comment: well it is working with foundation.css in the fiddle as you can see.I think you might have changed your default css file. Ya you can use inline css but better make a class and add it into you custom stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Tb9Vg/1/  But it has nothing to do with the Foundation itself.

html:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="small-2 large-4 columns">small-2 large-4 columns</div>
            <div class="small-4 large-4 columns">small-4 large-4 columns</div>
            <div class="small-6 large-4 columns">small-6 large-4 columns</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrap{
    padding-left:7%;
    padding-right:7%;
}
.columns{
    height: 500px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: This 100% fine without foundation.If include foundation.css above problem is existing.

Comment: @ParameshReddy You can wrap it and apply padding to the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

.row ( margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width : 30em;}

The margin-left and margin-right centers your element, and with width property you can set the size of your element as big as you like (30 is just an example). The benefit is that when you resize the screen, it retains distance from both sides.

Comment: Thanks user3754032,afer reading your answer I got knew that foundation is setting width for class row.Therefore just i hace increased that width and i got the Result.Thanks for your Help.

Comment: Dont change the .row class unless you want to reflect the change of width through out your web page.always add you custom classes separately and ovveride them.